# Heroku build for node app with unusual folder structure

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration

The project is divided into a backend code and react native client code.

Both are sharing one github project. It looks like this:

```
 backend/

--- src/

--- package.json

 client/

--- src/

--- package.json
```

For my heroku instance, I want to run **only the backend** code, but at the same time want to use continues integration feature from github.

Is there a way to make heroku run npm install & start only from the backend folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `package.json` in the root of the whole project (the parent dir of backend). You can do this with `npm init --yes`.

Give that top-level `package.json` file two scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd backend && npm install",
    "start": "cd backend && npm start"
}
```

Should do the trick.